# C# Date (server) => Json date/time (browser) => C# date/time with time portion (server) issue

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Context information: PST timezone, Asp.net Mvc legacy app with WebApi 2.x that uses json.net for serializing/deserialization to json, Chrome/FF browsers. The app is configured with:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified;
```

A tester reported an issue related to this date: 1977-04-15. Here is the flow:

- C# 1977-04-15 => Serialized to json as "1977-04-15T00:00:00" due to the use of Unspecified.
- In the browser (in the PST timezone) this is parsed as:

```
var dt = new Date("1977-04-15T00:00:00")
dt
Output: Date Fri Apr 15 1977 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

- Serialized back to the C# WebApi service:

```
JSON.stringify(dt);
Output: "\"1977-04-15T08:00:00.000Z\""
```

- Back in the C# world this becomes (I used linqpad):

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("1977-04-15T08:00:00.000Z"));
Output: 1977-04-15 01:00:00
```

It seems that C# used a different offset than the browser for the PST timezone at that date. I tested it in FF & Chrome. Is this normal?

What would be the best way to fix this?

One way would to configure the DateTimeZoneHandling to Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local but I am reluctant to do this on the existing app.

If I use local I have:

c#:

```
var date = new DateTime(1977, 04, 15); //, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
  DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
};
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(date, settings));
Ouput: "1977-04-15T00:00:00-07:00"
```

In the Javascript land:

```
"1977-04-15T00:00:00-07:00"
dt
Output: Date Thu Apr 14 1977 23:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
JSON.stringify(dt)
Output: "\"1977-04-15T07:00:00.000Z\""
```

Back in the C# land:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("1977-04-15T07:00:00.000Z"));
Output:1977-04-15 00:00:00
```

This seems to work, the dates match.

Update:

After more testing we have in C# (linqpad):

```
var date = new DateTime(1977, 04, 03, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
date.ToLongDateString().Dump();
date.ToUniversalTime().Dump();
date = new DateTime(1977, 04, 04, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
date.ToLongDateString().Dump();
date.ToUniversalTime().Dump();
Output:
Sunday, April 03, 1977
1977-04-03 08:00:00
Monday, April 04, 1977
1977-04-04 07:00:00
```

While in JavaScript (FF) we have:

```
var dt = new Date(1977, 3, 24); 
dt.toGMTString()
var dt = new Date(1977, 3, 25); 
dt.toGMTString()
Output:
"Sun, 24 Apr 1977 08:00:00 GMT"
"Mon, 25 Apr 1977 07:00:00 GMT"
```

There seems to be a discrepancy in the DST time tables.

I was curios about the Java world, so I ran this in scala:

```
scala> ZonedDateTime.of(1977, 4, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("PST")))
res8: java.time.ZonedDateTime = 1977-04-24T00:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

scala> ZonedDateTime.of(1977, 4, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("PST")))
res9: java.time.ZonedDateTime = 1977-04-25T00:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

It looks like C# is wrong. I have tested on a Windows 7 VM with .Net framework 4.8 (528049).

Update 2:

This is getting interesting. I tested F# on MacOs with .net core sdk 2.1.

```
    let mutable dt = System.DateTime(1977, 04, 24, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Local)
    printfn "%s" (dt.ToLongDateString())
    printfn "%A" (dt.ToUniversalTime())
    let dt = System.DateTime(1977, 04, 25, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Local)
    printfn "%s" (dt.ToLongDateString())
    printfn "%A" (dt.ToUniversalTime())
Output:
Sunday, April 24, 1977
4/24/77 8:00:00 AM
Monday, April 25, 1977
4/25/77 7:00:00 AM
```

Note the DST offset change.

Comment: Z means "Zulu time" (i.e. UTC+0). PST is -7, so I would expect 7 hours to be subtracted from an ISO8601 datetime ending in Z, if converted to local (PST) time.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that browser uses -8 hours while C# uses -7. Unless I am not seeing something obvious.

Comment: Are the timezone settings the same on the server as the client? Have there been any historical changes to daylight savings around this date that one might be taking notice of and the other might not?

Comment: Yes, they are the same, i.e. in the PST zone. I am not aware of any changes but I haven't looked. I am doing it now.

Comment: The browser reports the change to DST on 1977-04-25, i.e. the offset changed to -7 from -8. ```var dt = new Date(1977, 3, 25); dt.toGMTString();``` produces: "Mon, 25 Apr 1977 07:00:00 GMT" in FF.

Comment: After doing some tests in C#, the change of offset happened on 1977-04-04. ```var date = new DateTime(1977, 04, 04, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local); date.ToLongDateString().Dump(); date.ToUniversalTime().Dump();``` (linqpad)

Answer (score 0):

`<rant>`I have found using `DateTime` for dates frustrating`</rant>`

One way to deal with your issue is to extract the `.Date` (EDIT: or `new Date(orig.Year, orig.Month, orig.Day)`) part at some point to loose the time part.

---

Edit: re: comments:
This is a hack that could help. Ultimately each element of the pipeline needs to work correctly.

I find that the best way is to use either a string ("yyyy-MM-dd") or `int`s for the 3 parts.

Comment: I totally agree. And I think that's what I am going to do but I don't like it because I have to go back to find all the spots.

Comment: This is fairly dangerous unless you are only using a Single Timezone.

Comment: Yes, all my users are in the same timezone otherwise I would not do it. Thanks for pointing this out. I am going to do a lot of testing.

Comment: And you have to be careful of Time Zones that have Day Light Savings Time as it's theoretically possible for time to go backwards a day (I'm not a DLST expert, maybe it's not possible).